# Php, Wscript.shell makes Apache not responding

Tags: php, apache

I have a php script that starts another script to run in the background.
I have used exact this script before, but on my new computer it doesn't seem to work. When I execute it, Apache will stop responding, and I have to restart it.

Therefore I think there's maybe something wrong with the config or my environment in some way. Where can I find any clues?

Running Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.6.4 on Windows 7.

The code:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("\"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe\" ".DOCROOT."index.php --task=RenderQueue", 0, false);
```

The command is working just fine if I execute it through the command line.